# Flask Basic HTTP Auth use login page

Tags: python, flask, basic-authentication

I'm building a test app and used the instructions here (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) to setup simple authentication.  On pages where auth is required I get a popup saying "Authorization Required". 
Instead of that, I'd like to redirect to a login page where the user can put their user/pass in a form.

Here's what I have currently (same as the snippet in the link):

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, Response


def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """
    return username == 'admin' and password == 'secret'

def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'})

def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth or not check_auth(auth.username, auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

It looks like I could use Flask-Auth, but I really only need the functionality that the above provides.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/. There is a sample decorator that does just this:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import g, request, redirect, url_for

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Just return the redirect instead of calling the authenticate() method as you do now.