# Get next URL using flask redirect

Tags: python, flask

I am following this [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784002/flask-basic-http-auth-use-login-page), all seems good, but I need to know how to load the originally requested url from the new login page on the second to last line.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if not models.check_auth(username, password):
            error = 'Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for(**next**))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: Can you try using: `return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("index"))`?

Comment: I just realized the values were being passed in the url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if not models.check_auth(username, password):
            error = 'Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("admin"))
            #               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Comment: This seems to work as the information is being passed but I get a BuildError:

 BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint u'http://172.30.5.254/admin'. Did you mean 'admin' instead?